# Can I create multiple iOS certificates for the same app to create multiple onesignal apps

Tags: flutter, certificate, onesignal

I have a flutter app
And I want to create multiple oneSignal push notification apps
For the same app

And since every single OneSignal app need it’s own iOS certificate
(Regarding ios)

So can I create multiple iOS certificates for the same iOS app ??

Comment: Why do you use multiple Push notifications for a single app? Pls let us know

Comment: It is used to produce builds for different installations; for example builds for App Store releases vs Ad-Hoc install